# How to get yodlee invesment holding with top gainer and top looser?

Tags: yodlee

How to get Investment Holding from Yodlee?

- I want to show:
- Total Holdings
- last 30 days Holdings
- 1 day holdings

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to holdings information by calling-

https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/holdings/getHoldings **Get Holdings API**

upon successful account addition with Yodlee.

Comment: How can I get  Investment Holding filtered data by 1 day, 30 days? because there is no parameter for date there